# Updating video file in Dash app causes entire app to refresh

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

So I have a graph with some click data that has the location of video files in an S3 bucket. The idea is that when the user clicks on a point on the graph it will display a video related to that point, however, the app just seems to refresh.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import boto3
import dynamo_utils
import plotly_express as px
from datetime import datetime

s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='', aws_secret_access_key='')

df = dynamo_utils.query_site('data')

# Create a copy dataset so original isn't altered
ddf = df.copy()

dff = df.copy()
dff["Event"] = 1
# If a day, then


# Graph data

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([

dcc.Graph(
    id='scatter-plot',
    figure=px.scatter(dff, x=dff.Human_Time, y=dff.Event, custom_data=["Machine_Id", "Bucket", "File_Path"]),
     clickData={'points': [{'customdata': ""}]}
 # Set initial click data
),

    html.Div(
    children=html.Video(
        controls=True,
        id='video_player',
        src="",
        autoPlay=True,
        style={'width': "70%", 'text-align': 'center'}
    ),
    className="card",
    style={'text-align': 'center'}
),
])

@app.callback(Output('video_player', 'src'),
          [Input('scatter-plot', 'clickData')])
def updateVideo(clk_data):
# This will cause video data to appear if data in graph if clicked
# No need to display data if there is

    video_file = ""
    if clk_data is None:
        video_src = None
    else:
    # Get the current time for saving files
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H_%M_%S")
        print(clk_data)
    # clk_data allows us to get each
    # machineID = clk_data['points'][0]['customdata'][0]
        bucket = clk_data['points'][0]['customdata'][1].split(" ")[0]
        path = clk_data['points'][0]['customdata'][2]
        filePath = path.split(".")[0]

        print(filePath)
        print(bucket)

        try:

             s3.download_file(bucket, filePath + ".mp4", 'app/assets/' + "vid_" + str(current_time) + ".mp4")

        except:
             print("video not downloading")

        video_file = 'app/assets/'+ "vid_" + str(current_time) + ".mp4"


    return video_file,
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

This was previoyuly working fine when I was storing the downloaded videos in a static folder, however, the videos no longer seem to play at all when stored there.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? Or have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was much simpler than I expected, you have to return video_file as a dict

```
return [video_file]
```